# Free app for Windows to burn video (MP4, AVI, etc.) to VCD and SVCD

Tags: windows, gratis, video, optical-media

I only want software that can burn VCD or SVCD and **not** DVD. I am looking for software that can automatically convert it during the burning process, most of them are AVI MP4

I used to have a collection of VCDs and SVCDs and I want to burn videos but I can't burn DVDs and have some blank CDs.

Please no paid/trial apps. Only freeware. And also only for Windows 7 compatible.

**Update** I have found what I wanted,, it is **Ashampoo Burning Studio 6 Free**, there is no need for an answer now. I can convert the files as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Btw: On SE sites, it's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) – but answers should be posted as answers, not as part of the question-post. Mind [edit]ing that out of your question, and move it to a separate answer? Thanks in advance!